# Обновление ресурсов при компиляции

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, resources, ресурсы

Есть у меня COM-сервер, в который должна интегрироваться tlb. Собираю я его при помощи cmake (ToolChain Visual Studio 2019) такими командами

```
set(SOURCES ... myLib.idl myLib.rc)
add_executable(myLib.exe WIN32 ${SOURCES})

set(MIDL_OUTPUT
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myLib_i.h
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myLib_i.c
)

set(MIDL_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myLib.idl)

set(TLB_NAME "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myLib.tlb")
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${MIDL_OUTPUT}
        COMMENT "midl /h myLib_i.h /iid myLib_i.c /tlb ${TLB_NAME} /proxy myLib_p.c ${MIDL_FILE} /env x64 /W1 /char signed /robust /nologo /Oicf /target NT60"
        COMMAND midl /h myLib_i.h /iid myLib_i.c /tlb ${TLB_NAME} /proxy myLib_p.c ${MIDL_FILE} /env x64 /W1 /char signed /robust /nologo /Oicf /target "NT60"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
        DEPENDS ${MIDL_FILE}
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${MIDL_FILE}
        VERBATIM
)
target_sources(myLib.exe PRIVATE ${MIDL_FILE} ${MIDL_OUTPUT})
```

И `myLib.rc` файл

```rc
1 TYPELIB "myLib.tlb"
```

Проблема: после модификации idl файла в качестве ресурса добавляется tlb файл предыдущей версии. Пока я не сделаю общий build проекта

Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что при компиляции не обновляется файл `myLib.rc.res`. Как его заставить обновляться?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69767579/5376639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось так:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${MIDL_OUTPUT}
    COMMENT "midl /h myLib_i.h /iid myLib_i.c /tlb ${TLB_NAME} /proxy myLib_p.c ${MIDL_FILE} /env x64 /W1 /char signed /robust /nologo /Oicf /target NT60"
    COMMAND midl /h myLib_i.h /iid myLib_i.c /tlb ${TLB_NAME} /proxy myLib_p.c ${MIDL_FILE} /env x64 /W1 /char signed /robust /nologo /Oicf /target "NT60"
    COMMAND "C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/touch.exe" -c "-r${TLB_NAME}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/myLib.rc"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    DEPENDS ${MIDL_FILE}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${MIDL_FILE}
    VERBATIM
)
```

Я в `add_custom_command` добавил еще одну команду, которая, при создании tlb, изменяет дату создания rc файла. После этого компилятор сам пересобирает `myLib.rc.res`